# rails - concatante and minify css but ignore js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

Is it possible, using the asset pipeline on production, to seperate the minifcaiton & concatenation of js & css?

I want to have my css pre-compiled, but I'd like to leave my js files as they are in development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `application.js` file you can remove the line:

```
//= require_tree .
```

Which causes the asset pipeline to ignore your individual javascript files for concentration.

You can manually add any file you wish to be included in the application.js file instead.